# Jquery get nearest adjacent element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the nearest adjacent element. These two buttons are next to each other and I want to click button A to get get button B and to click button B to get button A. So basically it just detects the nearest adjacent button.

```
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

I tried this:

```
$(this).closest('button').text("ok");
```

And when clicking button A it selects itself! Apparently the closest button to button A....is button A. Not sure why it works like that. It's like the nearest person to me...is me.

EDIT: It's the same code for either button so next and prev wouldn't be that convenient. I'm assuming there's a selector for the closest element.

Comment: Read the documentation: [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to see *why* it behaves like that (by design). You're looking for [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next).

Comment: If I click button A with next() it selects button A but clicking button B does not select A with next. It's the same code for either button.

Comment: Are these elements wrapped in another containing element? If so, are there any other elements also in the container?

Comment: They're not wrapped but they could be wrapped in a div if need be. There are other buttons and also imgs. So it's simplest just to detect the nearest button. I thought that would be easy with jquery...no?

Comment: @David Thomas since either button just selects the other one it doesn't matter which one is which. All they're doing is selecting whichever button is nearest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.prev("button")` and `.next("button")` to select immediately previous and next siblings. And `.prevAll('button')` and `.nextAll("button")` to select all before and all after siblings.

```js
var counter = 0
$("button").click(function(){
    var closest_ones = $(this).prev("button").add($(this).next("button"));
    closest_ones.text(++counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
```

Comment: It's the same code for either button so that wouldn't work very well. I just need something like nearest('button).

Comment: $(this).prev('button').next('button').text("ok"); doesn't work and siblings() is even worse since it selects ALL the buttons.

Comment: Updated my answer.